# Protect against missbehaviour caused by twos compliment

Tags: integer-arithmetic

I read the following question: [Value of i for (i == -i && i != 0) to return true in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781150/258418) and was left slightly dazzled.

One reads about [spacecraft being lost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter) because of using the wrong unit system, so seeing the behaviour mentioned in the question and awnser is quite unexpected to me.

How does one protect against the errors/unexpected behaviour generated by this, without runtime penalty? (I find it hard to think of sensefull code with the `=` comparison, while I consider it rather simple for `abs` returning a negative value to fail). Are there exceptions to catch? Linters that warn about this?

---

**Unexpected Behaviour:**

java `abs()` returns the minimum negative number if the input is the minimum negative number.
-x=x has a solution other than 0, the minimal negative number in twos complement.

Comment: Use fuzzing tools that subject your code to edge cases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to either

1. Use sensible types in your system. Be aware that a machine int is not a mathematical integer. If your program may need to use numbers out of the range of a machine int, you should be using a big integer library, not machine ints.
2. Program defensively. If an operation might result in a value going out of range, then you should explicitly check for this after the operation is performed (or, even better, check *before* the operation to see if the arguments will cause an error).

Of course, if you do 2. you still have to decide what to do in case an error occurs, which you don't with 1. However, using big integers will incur a performance penalty in most languages. Whether that runtime penalty is greater or less than the penalty from performing safety checks will likely depend on the programming language and the specifics of your program.

In the end, it is the programmer's job to be responsible with the code that they write. The language can only provide you with so much help.

Comment: I understand that one should be on guard, but this is something I will overlook every time and did not even know about until I read the initial question. Thus I will first shoot myself in the foot (loose a satellite/my job/...) and then I might figure out the source. Is there an architecture that generates `exceptions` (overflow!)? Or are there library implementations arround where `abs` raises an exception(Runtime penalty for the added test every time but what can you do)?

Comment: tl;dr: Can I get exceptions. Exceptions are the solution for lazy programmers forgetting to check return codes of functions for errors. What is the equivalent to exceptions for the int issue?